# Storage issue with Key,Value datatypes, particularly Hstores in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

Say I have a table with 3 columns: `varchar(20), hstore, smallint`

Now if I insert the following: `"ABCDEF", "abc=>123, xyz=>888, lmn=>102", 5`

How much space will the record take in PostgreSQL? Is the `hstore` stored as plain text?
So if I have a million records, the space taken by the keys (abc,xyz,lmn) will be duplicated across *all* the records?

I'm asking this because I have a use case in which I need to store an unknown number of key,value pairs; with each key taking upto 20B and the value not more than smallint range.

The catch is that the number of records is massive, around 90 million a day. And the number of Key,Value pairs are ~400. This quickly leads storage problems since just a day's data would total upto around 800GB; with a **massive percentage being taken by the Keys which are duplicated across all records.**

So considering there are 400 Key/Value pairs, a single Hstore in a record (if stored as plain text) would take 400*22 Bytes. Multiplied by 90 Million, that is 737GB.
If stored in normal columns as 2 Byte ints, it will take just 67GB.

Are HStores not suitable for this use case? Do I have any option which can help me with this storage issue? I know this is a big ask and I might just have to go with a regular columnar storage solution and forgo the flexibility offered by key value.

Comment: I think hstore qualifies for compression like any other variable length data type: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/storage-toast.html  (and the upcoming 9.4 has an even more efficient hstore storage if I'm not mistaken). But if you have a "*massive percentage of Keys duplicated across all records*" then this sounds more like you want to store them in a separate table (and a regular column) and use a foreign key to avoid the duplication.

Answer (score 2):

> How much space will the record take in PostgreSQL?

To get the raw uncompressed size:

```
SELECT pg_column_size( ROW( 'ABCDEF', 'abc=>123, xyz=>888, lmn=>102'::hstore, 5) );
```

but due to [TOAST compressed out-of-line storage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) that might not be the on-disk size... though it often is:

```
CREATE TABLE blah(col1 text, col2 hstore, col3 integer);

INSERT INTO blah (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES ('ABCDEF', 'abc=>123, xyz=>888, lmn=>102'::hstore, 5);

regress=> SELECT pg_column_size(blah) FROM blah;
 pg_column_size 
----------------
             84
(1 row)
```

If you used a bigger `hstore` value here it might get compressed and stored out of line. In that case, the size would depend on how compressible it is.

> Is the hstore stored as plain text?

no, it's a binary format, but nor is it compressed; the keys/values are plain text.

> So if I have a million records, the space taken by the keys (abc,xyz,lmn) will be duplicated across all the records?

Correct. Each `hstore` value is a standalone value. It has no relationship with any other value anywhere in the system. It's just like a `text` or `json` or whatever else. There's no sort of central key index or anything like that.

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE hsdemo(hs hstore);

INSERT INTO hsdemo(hs) 
SELECT hstore(ARRAY['thisisthefirstkey', 'thisisanotherbigkey'], ARRAY[x::text, x::text]) 
FROM generate_series(1,10000) x;

SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('hsdemo'::regclass));
-- prints 992kb

INSERT INTO hsdemo(hs) 
SELECT hstore(ARRAY['thisisthefirstkey', 'thisisanotherbigkey'], ARRAY[x::text, x::text]) 
FROM generate_series(10000,20000) x;

SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('hsdemo'::regclass));
-- prints 1968kb, i.e. near doubling for double the records.
```

Thus, if you have many highly duplicated large keys and small values, you should probably look at a normalized schema (yes, even EAV).

However, be aware that PostgreSQL has quite a large per-row overhead of over 20 bytes per row, so you may not gain as much as you'd expect by storing huge numbers of short rows instead of something like a hstore.

You can always compromise - keep a lookup table of full key names, and associate it with a short hstore key. So your app essentially compresses the keys in each hstore.

Comment: That's very useful information, thanks a lot..! So if I understand correctly, on a non-indexed `hstore` with 200 key value pairs (in a table of 80 million rows); if I do a simple `SELECT myhstore->'somekey' from MYTABLE where WHERE date< somedate ;`, it will be very slow as compared to something like `SELECT mykeycolumn from MYTABLE where date<somedate` (in a simple columnar setup without hstores). I'm guessing this because Postgre will have to do a linear search through the 200 keys in each row's hstore to find `somekey` in each of the 80 million rows!

Comment: @user1265125 Yes, without an index it'll likely be slow. The GIN and GiST indexes that support hstore are also generally somewhat slower than normal b-tree indexes. *Howevever* it is not necessarily true that Pg will have to do a linear search through all 200 keys; `hstore` has an internal lookup table (it's a hashmap). Take a look at the documentation and the comments in the hstore source code for more details on that.